# Turn off setting in vim with open file

Tags: vim, vi

turn off setting in vim with open file

I use pyflakes plugin for python develpoment. It sometimes obscures the current line by turning it in red, (it thinks it is not syntactically correct, while the reality is I'm still in the process of writing it) and any string etc in it turns unreadable.

In my vimrc, I have the following 2 entries I added for pyflakes

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
```

How can I turn of filetype detection in open file for pyflakes to stop working? Basically, be able to load pyflakes when I wish, and unload it when needed

I tried writing `:filetype off` and `:filetype plugin off`, but neither seem to work.

The only working solution I can think of is to use another `vimrc` file, and create a bash alias for vim to open files with this other `vimrc`, but this means I will have to close the file everytime.

Comment: You can't really *unload* vim plugins that I know of.  Your best bet may be to change your color scheme in such a way that the combination of red with the string is still readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this option in your vimrc file to disable quickfix support:

```
let g:pyflakes_use_quickfix = 0
```